# Copy/paste produces wrong codepage characters

Tags: keyboard, vmware

When I copy/paste text into `nano` on a console window (Ctrl+Alt+F2), the braces and brackets are converted to German Umlaut characters. It's fine in a terminal running on the graphical Desktop.

That's probably because a German keyboard was detected during installation and I want a German keyboard.

How to make Copy/Paste work?

Output of `locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Output of `update-locale LANG=de-DE.UTF-8`:

```
*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8" LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8" LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8" LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8" LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8" LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8" LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8" LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8" LANG=de-DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
```

> VMWare Workstation 10.0, VMWare Tools installed
>   Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop 32 bit, almost clean installation, 1 day ago